# How to get access to that pointer?

Tags: c++, linked-list, iterator

I've got something like this:

```
template <typename T,typename K>
class Ring
{
  typedef struct Node
  {
          T data;
          K key;
          Node * next;
          Node * prev;
  };
  Node * head;
public:
   class iterator
   {
        private: 
        Node * ptr;
        friend class Ring; 
}
```

And I want to get by iterator class to Node*ptr to return in methods like get_value(iterator x) data and key. How can I do this ommiting function friend class? I want to make that Node *ptr will not be able to being used by user.

```
template <typename T,typename K>
K& Ring<T,K>::get_key(iterator & iter)
{
    Node * ptr = iter.ptr;
     return ptr->key;
}
```

I want to return ptr-> key of my node, but without friend class I don't have access to Node * ptr , so I totally don't know how to get acces to that values.

Comment: can you provide a code snippet of what you would like to write?

Comment: I have updated my answer to main question :)

Comment: why do you want to avoid friends? How would I construct such an iterator if I cannot access its `ptr`?

Comment: also it makes little sense to me that the `get_key` is a member of the `Ring`, as it merely returns `iterator.ptr->key`, what does this have to do with the `Ring` ?

Comment: `private: //protected:`?

Comment: I know that is not useful and i would do that with friend class, but my professor said that is forbidden tu use that, and i totally dont have any clue how to acces that ptr without that...

Comment: @StephanLechner just not important comment

Comment: `typedef struct Node` 1. This is C++ `typedef`ing structures is not necessary. 2. It's not being `typedef`ed as anything. Lose the `typedef`.

Comment: @tobi303 i though that it would help me to get acces to Node *ptr

Comment: you want to hide `iterator`s `Node* ptr` but you are searching for a way to get access to it..quite unclear what are the requirements

Comment: In order to have an iterator going through your `Node` elemens in `Ring` you'll need *at least* member functions `Node* begin() const` and `Node* end() const` for doing something like `for (const auto& node : myRing) { cout << node.data <<endl; }`

Comment: `friend` is the right solution. Alternative is a getter function, but then any fool with an `iterator` can `delete iter.getptr();`

Comment: Rethinking this a bit. You could also make `iterator` a bit smarter and add a `get_key` function to it.

Comment: So using friend there it wont allow normal user to get information about private data?

Comment: `friend` would restrict access to `ptr` and thus `key` to `iterator` and `Ring`. No one else gets access without playing undefined behaviour games. `iterator` exposing a `get_key` method exposes the `key` to anyone with an iterator, but does not expose `ptr`. The question is should owners of an `iterator` be able to access `key`?

Comment: Without that how i can shuffle 2 rings? In my case i'm taking ring one, then i'm taking ring.begin() which is giving me iterator - and i just have iterator right now so if i want to push 2nd element to another ring im doing x=get_key(iter) and then i'm doint r3.push(x). Is there another smart way to do this?

Comment: You could have `Ring Ring::shuffle(Ring & other)` that shuffles `this` and `other` into an Automatic `Ring` that you then return. Then nothing is exposed except `Ring`s. I think you need to sit down and put together a requirements document that outlines what you want exposed and to who before proceeding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at the API for std:map, std::unordered_map, to see how they've overcome this issue.

as in :

```
std::pair<const K&, T&> std::map::iterator<K, T>::iterator::operator*();
```

Dereferencing a std::map::iterator gives you references to both a key and a value, conveniently hiding the implementation details.

This approach would fit well with your container as well.